# Different digital signal input voltage than running voltage

Tags: integrated-circuit

I assume running an IC at one voltage (3.3v), and having the (digital) signal input be at a different voltage (5v) is fine. If both of these voltages are within the operating range of the chip, am I right in my assumptions?

Is this chip-dependent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not fine. Some inputs have protection diodes which are purposely integrated to prevent the thing you're about to do. In such event current flows from the input source to the Vcc of the circuit. If your input source has a low internal resistance, it's a straight short circuit, which most of the time triggers the overload protection of the voltage regulator in your circuit or destroys the diode inside the chip or far more.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the 3.3V chip is "5V tolerant" for the specific inputs you are using it may be okay. If it doesn't say that it is, it probably isn't. Another hint is the maximum input voltage specification. If Vdd is 3.3V and absolute maximum input voltage for the input in question is Vdd + 0.3V, then 5V would be a problem.

Going the other way (3.3V output to input on a 5V chip) the '1' level may not be high enough to be reliable.

There may also be issues with supply sequencing- a 3.3V input applied to a 5V chip may be within tolerance for a logic '1', but if the 3.3V supply comes up before (or stays up after) the 5V supply then a potentially harmful condition could occur where a lot of current flows into the ESD protection network. In the worst case, the 5V supply then comes up and the chip latches up, causing the 5V chip to be destroyed.

Most of these problems can be avoided by using a voltage converter chip with two different supply voltages, though there are potentially cheaper solutions that work well enough in some cases.